# Database-specific "No matching authentication protocol" error using Oracle 8

Tags: authentication, oracle8i

Let me start off by saying I have reviewed all questions on SO regarding this error, but either the exact problem differed from mine, or the solution did not work.

I am setting up a new Windows server with Oracle 8 (we can't upgrade because that is what the vendor is using). Trying both PL/SQL Developer and SQL Plus as the client, I receive a "No matching authentication protocol" error when trying to log in to one specific database. I have no problem logging into other databases. I can successfully log in to this database on our old Windows server that this one is replacing, where the file structure and tnsnames.ora file is the same.

Here's what I have tried, unsuccessfully:

1. Setting the `SQLNET.ALLOWED_LOGON_VERSION` parameter to 8, 10, 11 (default), 12, and 12c in the sqlnet.ora file (one at a time).
2. Changing the parameter to `SQLNET.ALLOWED_LOGON_VERSION_SERVER`, keeping at 8.
3. Adding `SQLNET.ALLOWED_LOGON_VERSION_CLIENT` parameter to sqlnet file, with a
   value of 8 as well.
4. Using jdbc6.jar instead of jdbc14.jar under E:\oracle\10.2.0\jdbc\lib

I'm waiting on a response from the vendor regarding whether they have restricted access by IP. Outside of that possibility, I'm at a standstill here.

Answer (score 1):

Try to set the following JDBC driver property `oracle.jdbc.thinLogonCapability` to `o3`. This will make the driver try to use the old o3logon authentication protocol which is the only protocol Oracle 8 supports.

Comment: Actually, after reviewing, I'm frustrated to learn that the vendor's Oracle instance is 10g, not 8. Therefore, this issue no longer exists for me. I'll leave this question open for further answers (and in case other users encounter this issue), but I hesitate to mark this answer accepted. 

If you or any admins would care to comment on what the procedure here would be, feel free! Thanks for your answer, Jean de Lavarene.